# Conditional configuration in VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VS Code extension; the extension has its configurations. I hope when users are editing the `settings.json`, some of the configuration properties can be displayed conditionally. For example:

```json
{
   "foo": //...
   "bar": //...
}
```

I hope the property `"bar"` only appear when the `"foo"` is set to a specific value.

Does VS Code support to achieve that in the extension's `package.json`?

Comment: look at the JSON scheme definition you can set if this is possible. AFAIK, the scheme is defined for a particular setting, it has no knowledge of other settings

Comment: Does that mean is not achievable?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can use `if`, `then`, `else`.

Something like:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "const": "a"
    }
  }
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "bar": {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```